# How to send data to a websocket from outside of consumer django channels

Tags: python, django, redis, channel

I'm trying to send data to a websocket from outside of the consumer

so i did following:

*settings.py*

```py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

*routing.py*

```py
from django.urls import path

from .consumers import CoinsListConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/coins/', CoinsListConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

*asgi.py*

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

from apps.coins.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                websocket_urlpatterns,
            )
        )
    )
})
```

*consumers.py*

```py
class CoinsListConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        logger.info('Websocket was connected.')
        await self.accept()
    
    async def disconnect(self, code):
        logger.warning('Websocket was disconnected.')
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        return await super().receive(text_data, bytes_data)
```

well this is ok and when i go to a view... the websocket will connect very well

but when i want to send data to the websocket.

```py
def send_data_to_websocket_coins_list_view(data: List[Dict]) -> None:
    """Send data to websocket coins list view """
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(json.dumps(data))
```

This did not work and raised following error
`TypeError: send() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'`

Also in the documentation this is should work by following code

```py
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("channel_name", json.dumps({...}))
```

its also not worked and raise the following error
`AssertionError: message is not a dict`

So what is the problem? what should i do?

Comment: According to the documentation, the `channel_layer.send` method accepts two parameters: `channel_name: str` and `message: dict`, therefore try sending the message without dumping the `data`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dump data

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in an ApiView for example:

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class NotificationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Process the notification
        notification_data = {'message': 'New notification'}

        # Send the notification to the WebSocket consumer
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'notifications',
            {'type': 'send_notification', 'text': json.dumps(notification_data)}
        )

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```